# How to use "hint" parameter with pymongo's delete_many()

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Per https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html, for `delete_many()`, **hint** was added in 3.11. Our pymongo:

```
>>> pymongo.__version__
'3.12.1'
```

We are trying to use this parameter to more quickly delete rows from our database:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from pymongo import ASCENDING, DESCENDING, TEXT
import os
MONGO_URI = os.getenv('MONGO_URI')

# connect to db
cluster = MongoClient(MONGO_URI)
db = cluster["cbbap"]

# set function parameter values
our_filter = { 'competitionId': { '$in': [30629, 30630] } }
our_hint = { 'competitionId': 1 } # competitionId is an index in our collection
table_name = 'our_table'

# this line works just fine
db[table_name].delete_many(filter = our_filter)
```

We run into problems when we try

```
# this line does not work
db[table_name].delete_many(filter = our_filter, hint = our_hint)
```

Returning Error: `TypeError: passing a dict to sort/create_index/hint is not allowed - use a list of tuples instead. did you mean [('competitionId', 1)]?`

So we try:

```
# does not work
our_hint = [('competitionId', 1)]
db[table_name].delete_many(filter = our_filter, hint = our_hint)
```

Returning Error: `pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: BSON field 'delete.deletes.hint' is an unknown field.` And we also tried

```
# does not work
db[table_name].delete_many(filter = our_filter, hint = 'competitionId')
```

as the docs say a string can be passed, however this does not work either, returning the same error `pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: BSON field 'delete.deletes.hint' is an unknown field.`.

How can we use the **hint** parameter with pymongo's delete_many function? What are we doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine with me.

[hint](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/operations.html#pymongo.operations.DeleteMany) in `DeleteMany` is only supported on MongoDB 4.4 and above.

```py
@app.get("/delete/{id}")
async def root(id: int):
    db = get_database()
    our_filter = { 'competitionId': { '$in': [30629, 30630] } }
    our_hint = [('competitionId', 1)]
    c = db['key'].delete_many(filter = our_filter,hint = our_hint)
    return {"message": c.deleted_count}
```

Comment: Is this python or mongo CLI? I guess I could give mongo CLI a try

Comment: I try it on python with `fastapi`. Make sure your MongoDB version is 4.4 or above.

Comment: Do i need mongodb installed when using `pymongo`. the requirement is a bit confusing because it says in the docs that I need pymongo 3.11+ which I have, but i don't actually have mongo installed where we are running this code, just `pymongo`

Comment: Yes, you need mongodb installed. [pymongo](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/python/) is the recommended driver to work with MongoDB using Python.

Comment: we use mongodb atlas and we only have version `4.2.`, so this was the issue... seems like upgrading from 4.2 to 4.4 is not a small upgrade so we will hold off on that for now. Thanks!